# Is $z_0$ an isolated singularity of $\frac {1}{g(z)}$ given it is a pole of $g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ be a pole (non-essential singularity) of order $k$ of the complex function $g(z)$.
Is $z_0$ an isolated singularity of $ \frac{1}{g(z)}$? If yes which type of singularity?

From my book "Conway's Functions of One Complex variable" the following is taken: Note that if $f$ has a pole at $a$, then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ has a removable singularity there and extends
to $a$ with value $0$."

So we know $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{1}{g(z)}$. How can I show/prove this statement?

Comment: If $z_0$ is a pole of $g$, then $g(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to z_0$. This means that there are no zeros of $g$ arbitrarily close to $z_0$. This implies that $1/g$ is analytic in some punctured neighborhood of $z_0$. Therefore, $z_0$ is an isolated singularity for $1/g$. That it is removable follows from $|g|$ being bounded from below by a positive number near $z_0$, which gives a bound from above for $1/|g|$.

Comment: Thank you, how do we know that $|g|$ is bounded from below by a positive number near $z_0$?

Comment: We know it from it tending to $\infty$ as $z\to z_0$. The meaning of it is that for all $M>0$ there is a $delta >0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<\delta$ then $|g(z)|>M$.